# How do I stop my file from being an unrecognised file?

Tags: java, file, netbeans

When I hover over the file name on the netbeans IDE, there is a tooltip that says "unrecognised file".

I think that could cause problems. These are non java files .txt etc, that are associated with my program. As a beginner, I'm not sure how to deal with .txt files.

I need those files to be recognised, but the fact they are not could cause problems.

Comment: Why do you think that could cause problems?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj i need them as inputs for methods in my program

Comment: I don't know netbeans, but I'm quite confident that you can safely ignore this "problem". Your program should be able to run without the IDE and what does the IDE think about these files is irrelevant. It's your program which need to read them.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans not recognizing a file type will not cause you any problems, but depending on the situation you may be able to make your life easier by asking NetBeans to treat the file of unknown type as a file of some known type.

For example, in the screen shot below, `newfile.xyz` is an unrecognized file. If you select that file node and then right-click to open the context menu, there is an `Open As...` menu entry.

[image: unrecognized1]

Clicking `Open As...` will open open the `Open as...` window where you can specify that the unknown file type is to be treated as though it were a file of some known type.

[image: unrecognized2]

For example, if you opened `newfile.xyz` as a file of type SQL, then the editing and formatting rules that apply to SQL files (i.e. files with extension *sql*) will also apply for files with an extension of *xyz*.